# Need to implement a filter to my WPF Datagrid using Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, filter, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid where in i am populating the data from the datatable using itemsource. Now I want to apply textbox filter for my Datagrid or (apply filter to the column header if possible). I am very new to WPF so could anyone please help me resolving this.

Note : I am not using MVVM , i am just using simple WPF datagrid

```
Currently my code is like below:
XAML Code:
-------------------

 <Page.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HeaderBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6B6EB9" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6B6EB9" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6B6EB9" Offset="0.509"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6B6EB9" Offset="0.542"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6B6EB9" Offset="0.542"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF9699DC" Offset="0.904"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HeaderBorderBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF1060D1" Offset="0.614"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF316BD5" Offset="0.853"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFBBD3ED" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HeaderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource HeaderBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgExcel"  LoadingRow="dgExcel_LoadingRow" RowEditEnding="dgExcel_RowEditEnding" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="dgExcel_AutoGeneratingColumn" ItemsSource = "{Binding}" ColumnWidth="Auto"  SelectionChanged="dgExcel_SelectionChanged" CanUserAddRows="True"  Loaded="dgExcel_Loaded" CellEditEnding="dgExcel_CellEditEnding" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF3F3F3">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

### Code file for loading  wpf datagrid:

```
 private void dgExcel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    string ConeectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\\Test.xlsx';" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"");
            OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection(ConeectionString);
            System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", oconn);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
            DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dgExcel.DataContext = DtSet.Tables[0];
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            //actionsGrid.ItemsSource = DtSet.DefaultViewManager;
            dt = DtSet.Tables[0];
            dgExcel.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;  
            oconn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a text box. You can find fancier textboxes with buttons to clear the text, or actively hit the button to search, but for now, just a simple one. Make sure it's named, and add a `TextChanged` event handler.

```
<TextBox x:Name="searchBox" TextChanged="SearchTextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

You then want to connect to your `CollectionView`. You may be directly assigning it, or using a `CollectionViewSource` element in the XAML code. Here's a basic version:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="collectionView" Source="{Binding OrderCollection}"
                          Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

This assumes an `ObservableCollection` has been set up in the code behind or view model.

```
public ObservableCollection<Orders> OrderCollection { get; } = //collection of orders
```

The `DataGrid`'s `ItemSource` would then point to the `CollectionViewSource` as a static resource binding.  There are other ways to construct this (for example, the direct connection to the `dt.DefaultView`), but I'll leave that for you to configure.

In the text changed event handler of your `TextBox` you want to refresh your view, so every time the user enters a new character it will re-evaluate the filter:

```
private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshView();
}

void RefreshView()
{
    var viewSource = (CollectionViewSource)Resources["collectionView"];
    viewSource?.View?.Refresh();
}
```

Caveat: This won't handle pasted text. There's a separate set of events for that.

When the view is refreshed, it will run the individual items of the `ItemsSource` through the `Filter` of the collection view. Then just set whether to accept each item or not.

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is DataRow row)
    {
        if (searchBox.HasText)
        {
            e.Accepted = Filter(row, searchBox.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}

private bool Filter(DataRow row, string filterText)
{
    // check if row matches the filterText
    // check whichever columns of the row are appropriate
    return true;
}
```

There are different ways this stuff can be hooked together, but this should cover the basic necessities.  I didn't check that the datatypes I expect for your data were the actual ones passed through the event handlers, so be sure to double-check that.